# AppFabric hosting/management replacement

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, appfabric

With the news from April that Microsoft will be ending support for AppFabric 1.1 April 2016. Can anyone recommend replacement services for Hosting and Management/Monitoring of Services and Workflows.

Microsoft suggest customers can manually host their own services #copOut and custom solutions can be built to produce management and monitoring #copOutAgain.

I am only beginning to investigate WCF for middletier and AppFabric seemed ideal. Seems such a pity that they are going to end it after only 5 years without giving good reason.

[AppFabric end of support blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2015/04/02/windows-server-appfabric-1-1-ends-support-4-2-2016.aspx)

Comment: For Workflow services, there don't seem to be any viable alternatives yet, though there is still time for someone to come out with a product.

Comment: FWIW, the [AppFabric support lifecycle has been extended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2015/06/19/appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server-support-lifecycle-extension-4-11-2017.aspx) until April 2017 (mainstream support) and April 2022 (extended support) respectively. So there's still some time for alternative solutions to spring up... I hope.

Comment: The reason isn't hard to discern. Why support a free framework when you can tell everyone to use Azure's PaaS offerings (and extract a monthly fee)?

Answer (score 5):

The end of support was extended until 4/12/2022. Advice on how and where to migrate are recommended in the [official article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2015/06/19/appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server-support-lifecycle-extension-4-11-2017.aspx) of Microsoft.  They talk about [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) and a new project [RedisOnWindows](https://msopentech.com/opentech-projects/redis/#) from MSOpen Tech.

more information check out the [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2015/06/19/appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server-support-lifecycle-extension-4-11-2017.aspx)

Comment: To support this answer you can checkout the AppFabric migration guides and other stuff to NCache from [here](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/appfabric-migration.html)

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for appfabric-cache migration alternatives I recommend to check out this blog from memurai https://www.memurai.com/blog/appfabric-caching-migration-guide

According to the official Microsoft product lifecycle, the extended support for [AppFabric 1.1 will end in 2022](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=AppFabric%201.1%20for%20Windows%20Server)

Most of the links from the previous response are broken and the MSOpen Tech Redis on Windows is retired or archived.